# Chunk list of strings by common prefix

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a function that extracts longest common prefix of strings rounded on the last whole word. For example, if I have list:

```
BRIGGS & STRATTON 290400 
BRIGGS & STRATTON 290700 
BRIGGS & STRATTON 294400 
BRIGGS & STRATTON 294700
```

and I call `longestPrefix(array);` it will return `BRIGGS & STRATTON`.

I am trying to chunk list of strings into sublists, grouped by the nonempty common prefix, but I can't get any my thought to work.

**Edit:**

Sample list is generated in that way that for two successive elements, my function either returns empty or nonempty string:

```
ALLIS-CHALMERS 816 
ALLIS-CHALMERS 818 
ALLIS-CHALMERS 917 AND 919 
ARIENS GT-17 
ARIENS GT-18 AND GT-19 
BOLENS 1600 
BOLENS 1700 
BOLENS 1900 HT-18 
BOLENS HT-20 AND HT-23 
BOLENS QT-16 
BRIGGS & STRATTON 290400 
BRIGGS & STRATTON 290700
```

Comment: No; it will return `BRIGGS & STRATTON 29`

Comment: @Slaks It is "rounded on the last whole word", so it will return BRIGGS & STRATTON.

Comment: @cardell0, I am trying to do gymnastics with GroupBy linq function, but I am not sure how to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `longestPrefix(array)` could potentially be different for each non-empty subset of your set. Additionally, each string may belong to multiple "groups", depending on what other items are there in a group: for example, if the original list contained some `BRIGGS & SON` items, the `BRIGGS & STRATTON` items could have been grouped with `BRIGGS &` items as well.

If you redefine the requirement as grouping by the *longest* common prefix, you could compute pairwise common prefixes, get the longest one, and group by it, like this:

```
void AddLongest(IDictionary<string,string> dict, string s, string p) {
    string current;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(s, out current) || p.Length > current.Length) {
        dict[s] = p;
    }
}

var longestPrefix = new Dictionary<string,string>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != myStrings.Length ; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1 ; j != myStrings.Length ; j++) {
        var common = FindLongestPrefix(new[] {myStrings[i], myStrings[j]});
        AddLongest(longestPrefix, myStrings[i], common);
        AddLongest(longestPrefix, myStrings[j], common);
    }
}
// Now you can use LINQ to group by the longest common prefix:
var groups = myStrings.GroupBy(s => longestPrefix[s]);
```

Comment: First, thank you for answering. When I try to run your code, I get "The given key was not present in the dictionary." exception on `GroupBy()` method?

Comment: Also, for now I changed longestPrefix method to return longest prefix in an array.

Comment: @Burgos I think I know what was wrong there - I tried fixing it, take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: This line of code does not compile `var common = longestPrefix(new[] {myStrings[i], myStrings[j]});` What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @shekky That's OP's `longestPrefix(array)` method. I accidentally called my dictionary the same name.